# Can I tell a nodeJs server to generate just the dynamic HTML (while nginx sends the static data) and then automatically send to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx

I have mostly dealt with Apache and php and am starting to play around with nginx and node.  I am really liking it.  I started with an Express server that handles sending all the website files and HTML rendering (Handlebars).

But that seemed a little sluggish and I looked at the benchmarks and it seems that node isn't the best for sending HTML on the fly.  I know having just static files saved to your nginx server is considered the fastest way to get user's their page requests.

I know you can set up a proxy in nginx to go to your node server. But my question is can you mix nginx and a nodejs server to get the best of both worlds?  So a user asks for a page from nginx. Nginx sends back all the static files for the website. Right as it sends those files can it tell the node server to create the dynamic content for the page that was requested as HTML then send it off to the user asap. I feel like doing this would cause for a faster page load time (maybe I'm naive and it won't make a difference).

The other question is how would the receiving of that dynamic HTML go? Can I set up like just the receiving part of a GET request for the data in javascript so when the page loads it GETs ready and waits for the dynamic HTML so it can grab it and put it in the correct places.  Otherwise I feel like if I have the node server send HTML to the client it will just take that as a new page and trash the previously loaded nginx static data it just received and load just the dynamic data.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question/concern is. Nginx is an event based http and reverse proxy server that is design for low memory usage and  high throughput. So you set up your server so that nginx handles all requests, and based on the url either sends the static files directly, forwards the request to other services like nodejs, or does a combination of both, e.g. `try_files /public/$uri /static/$uri @some_proxy_like_node;`

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to accomplish this, it all depends on how you want to construct your server.

Personally, I like to write client-side javascript which makes http requests to my server for content. That content is then processed and rendered in the web page. This is called AJAX. jQuery has methods that make writing AJAX requests quite simple. You can read up on it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Generally speaking, it is much more difficult for the server to send the client resources that they didn't ask for than it is for the client to make a request for the resource. The former would require a socket to stay open, listening for messages from the server. This isn't a bad solution, in fact this is the better solution for when your client and server should be in constant communication. However, in the scenario you are describing, it makes more sense for the client to request resources.